# At which points is the function $f(x)= \lim\limits _{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{1+(2\sin x)^{2n}}$ discontinuous?

Tags: analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Testing continuity of the function $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{(2\sin{x})^{2n}+1} \ \text{for} \ x \in \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57155/testing-continuity-of-the-function-fx-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracx)

I cannot figure out, at which points the function is discontinuous, the only thing came to my mind is solving $ 1+(2\sin x)^{2n} = 0$ which has no answer,  would be great to know the rule for such functions.

$$ f(x)=\lim _{n \to \infty} \frac{x}{1+(2\sin x)^{2n} }$$